# change a related field without mutating the original one

Tags: graphql, prisma

I have this schema:

```
type Game {
  id: ID! @id
  status: Boolean @default(value: false)
  time: DateTime!
  location: String!
  stadium: String!
  teams: [Team!]! @relation(name: "BothTeams")
}
type Team {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  abbrName: String!
  teamLogo: String!
  score: Int @default(value: 0)
  games: [Game!]! @relation(name: "BothTeams")
}
```

the Game type is gonna return typically two teams and each team is gonna have a score field.

so if i want to update a game later, specifically the score field,

i would have to change the score of every game with that changed team.

So, is there a way to change the score of a specific game, without mutating the original score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, a `score` is not really a property of a particular team. You want to represent it as a separate entity that's associated to *both* a team and a game. One way to do that:

```
type Game {
  id: ID! @id
  status: Boolean @default(value: false)
  time: DateTime!
  location: String!
  stadium: String!
  teams: [Team!]! @relation(name: "BothTeams")
  scores: [Score!]! @relation(name: "ScoresByGame")
}
type Team {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  abbrName: String!
  teamLogo: String!
  games: [Game!]! @relation(name: "BothTeams")
}
type Score {
  id: ID! @id
  value: Int @default(value: 0)
  team: Team @relation(name: "ScoreTeam")
}
```

Or instead of `scores`, you could have a `homeScore` field and an `awayScore` field. Either way, you'll have a `Score` node that you can mutate without impacting other games. Any other properties of a `Team` that might vary with each game should be treated similarly (for example, if you wanted to include what players played that particular game).

Comment: That would be a better way to approach it, thanks Daniel for the help.

Comment: `Game.status` also should be extracted while building 'append only' system. 'Versioned' score can contain time (offset to game start) and player (change 'author') - build game timeline (last one => game result). Score should be ralated to Game (reverse to ScoresByGame) - f.e. for list of games the player has changed the result.